# Changing window.location.href in Mocha/Karma stack

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, karma-runner

I am using Karma/Mocha for my test environment. I have js file which depends on window.location.href to get the url. When I am running tests using Karma, the default url is www.localhost:3123/context.html. Is it possible to change the url/add paramaters or say to karma to use custom url for this particular test suite?

```
//JS file has
function populate(){
   var url = new URL(window.location.href);
   -- check if the url have parameter, lets say carInfo
   -- if has then dispatches an event
}

//Mocha test
describe('...', function() {
    it ('...', function() {
       -- call populate()
       -- listen if the event was triggered
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In General try to separate dependencies in your Code so that you are able to Exchange these dependencies in Tests. The concept behind this is called *inversion of control*. You could also consider to take *dependency injection* into account.

In your concrete case `window.location.href` is a dependency that is specific to a special environment, the browser, which does not exist when running Tests in node.js or something

i.e.

```
function populate(url){
   // trigger the event...
}

describe('...', function() {
   it ('...', function() {
      populate(new URL("http://...")
      // listen if the event was triggered
   })
```

})